# count orders where 2 products appear

Tags: excel

I've been struggling with this one for a couple of day's. I have a table with orders and products. What i'm attempting to do is count the amount of times 2 products appeared together on an order, the table looks someting similar to this;

[table orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBFDE.jpg)

I need to count the number of orders that e.g. 'jacket' and  'jumper' were on the same order.

The output table looks something like this;

[output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNUo7.jpg)

For context, i'm trying to understand how best to set up related products for a website project.

Any help would be genuinely appreciated.

Many thanks,
Stephen

Comment: apologies my starting point was 

=SUM(IF((D3:H7="jumper")+(D3:H7="jacket"),1,0))

Comment: This would be much much easier if your data was structured `order_id | product` with orders taking up multiple rows, one for each product.

Comment: Hi J, many thanks for the prompt response, the original raw data came that way you suggest, so i do have that available to me

Comment: ord_id | prod_desc
ORD_001 | jacket
ORD_001 | jumper
ORD_001 | shoes
ORD_002 | jumper
ORD_002 | shirt
ORD_002 | tie
ORD_002 | shoes
ORD_003 | jacket
ORD_004 | shirt
ORD_004 | jumper
ORD_004 | tie
ORD_005 | shirt
ORD_005 | tie
ORD_005 | socks
ORD_005 | shoes
ORD_005 | shirt
ORD_006 | jumper
ORD_006 | shirt
ORD_006 | shoes
ORD_006 | socks
ORD_007 | shirt
ORD_007 | tie
ORD_008 | jacket
ORD_008 | shoes
ORD_008 | tie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use vba and create a UDF:

```
Public Function countArr(rng As Range, crit1 As String, crit2 As String) As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    Dim rngArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, h1 As Boolean, h2 As Boolean

    rngArr = rng
    For i = LBound(rngArr, 1) To UBound(rngArr, 1)
        h1 = False
        h2 = False
        For j = LBound(rngArr, 2) To UBound(rngArr, 2)
            If rngArr(i, j) = crit1 And crit1 = crit2 Then
                If Not h1 Then
                    h1 = True
                Else
                    h2 = True
                End If
            ElseIf rngArr(i, j) = crit1 Then
                h1 = True
            ElseIf rngArr(i, j) = crit2 Then
                h2 = True
            End If
        Next j
        If h1 And h2 Then countArr = countArr + 1
    Next i
End Function
```

Put this in a mdule attached to the workbook, **not** in the worksheet code or thisworkbook code:

[image]

Then you would call it like any other formula:

```
=countArr($B$2:$F$6,B$9,$A10)
```

[image]

Comment: @joepike did this work for you? If so please mark as correct. It is something only you can do. If not, then please let me know where it failed so I can fix it.

Comment: just tested and it works beautifully! 

Many thanks for your time and generosity.. Cheers Scott